# open new flow from another flow

Tags: jsf-2, spring-webflow-2

We have a "Home page" with multiple functionality and one of them is Account command link. Home page is define in the main-flow.xml(see below) and when we will click this link, the new flow should open.

**main_page.xhtml file:**

```
<h:commandLink value="Account" target="_blank" action="account"/>
```

**main-flow.xml file:**

```
<view-state id="main_page">

<transition-state on="account" to="newFlowOpen"/>

</view-state>

<view-state id="newFlowOpen" view="/Report/account.xhtml"/>
```

But when we click this link, than instead of opening new flow like e2s1, its simple opening new execution key with same flow execution like e1s2 which wrong.
Please advise me on this :(

Answer (score 0):

Because you added "newFlowOpen" as a view-state inside the main-flow.xml thus it is a part of main-flow.xml and not an independent stand alone flow.

If you want to create an independent stand alone flow you need to create a new "account-flow.xml" in it's own path. Once you do this the account link on the "Home page" once clicked will leave the existing flow and create a new account-flow.

If holding on/remembering the the main-flow state is important... **OPTIONALLY** (after doing the above), you can embed the newly created stand alone account flow inside the main-flow as a subflow.

Reasons to create a subflow relationship between parent->child flow:

- When you want to pass parameters or POJOs between 2 flows (without embedding the parameters inside the url)
- When you want preserve the parent flow's current state(s) and return back to the parent flow once the child flow is completed.

Below is a good example of how to create a subflow:

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-web-flow-subflow-webapp.html

```
<!-- You would place the subflow-state below inside main-flow.xml -->

    <subflow-state id="accountSubflow" subflow="account"> 
        <input name="id" value="accountId"/> <!-- input to send to subflow-->
        <input name="person" value="person" type="foo.bar.entities.Person"/> <!-- input to send to subflow for pojos you have explicitly declare the type-->

        <output name="boolSuccess" /> <!-- output returned by the subflow -->

        <transition on="save" to="saveForm"/>  <!-- "save" = id of the <end-state id="save"> inside the subflow -->
        <transition on="cancel" to="cancelForm" /> <!-- "cancel" = id of the <end-state id="cancel"> inside the subflow -->
    </subflow-state>
```